# swift animate spritekit with damping effect

Tags: ios, swift, animation, sprite-kit

I've been searching on the internet for several days, I didn't find what I'm looking for.
I'm working on an iOS game and I would like to move some sprites using `usingSpringWithDamping` (to have some rubber effect when moving my sprites).

I have found many solutions for UIViews but nothing for SKSpriteNode.

I would like to move a SKSpriteNode from position 1 to position 2 with a Damping effect.

Can you please give me some ideas?
Thanks.

C.C.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

UIView animations have support for spring animations, but these are not available in SpriteKit.

There is a third-party library on GitHub which extends `SKAction` with spring animations: https://github.com/ataugeron/SpriteKit-Spring

Comment: Not bad at all. I'm wondering if, after the Keynote next week, we will have some new stuff available.

Comment: The new iOS 11 API's were announced at WWDC 2017 back in June. There was no discussion of new timing curves for SpriteKit.

Comment: Do you know if I can do the following: my sprite will move from point A to point B. It will bounce a little bit before stopping (using the  third-party) it will collide with another sprite. Is there a way that this other sprite bounce a bit (rubber effect) without living his position ?

Comment: You could create another action, and run it on the other object when a collision occurs. If you are still having difficulty, I would post a separate Stack Overflow question.

Comment: Ok, I got it. Thanks.

Comment: I have tried to install the library, it does not works, it's too old. Last commit in 2014.

Comment: There is a pull request that is updated to the latest Swift version: https://github.com/ataugeron/SpriteKit-Spring/pull/16

Answer (score 5):

The Sprite Kit Utils from Ray Wenderlich (https://github.com/raywenderlich/SKTUtils) could be what you are looking for. Specifically, using SKTEffects and SKTTimingFunctions will allow you to add easing to your SKActions.

For example `SKTTimingFunctionElasticEaseIn`, `SKTTimingFunctionElasticEaseOut`, and `SKTTimingFunctionElasticEaseInOut` have the rubber effect you are looking for, but you may need to tweak them to your needs. Ray's utils also have other easing functions available; there is a good reference on different easing functions at: http://easings.net

Hope this helps!

Comment: Actually, I'm a big fan of Ray Wenderlich and the videos available. I didn't knew this library. I will try it. Thanks.